# find indices of values within tolerance range in R

Tags: r

say I have vector x

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1.1, 2, 1, 2.1, 2.6)
tol <- 0.4
```

how do I get the indices of the groups of elements that are 'unique' within the tolerance range (`tol`) as in the list below. I don't know how many of these groups there are beforehand.

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 5

[[2]]
[1] 4 6

[[3]]
[1] 7
```

thanks

Comment: What happens if tolerance ranges overlap? `x <- c(1, 1.3, 1.6)`

Comment: I don't know why I don't understand your question :-? How that list is generated?

Comment: @m0h3n: I hope the question is clearer now. The list is the answer I want

Comment: @Roland Good point. Then I'd like to get the indices of three groups; i.e. 1&2, 1&2&3 and 2&3

Comment: Hi @Lukas if any answer solves your problem please mark it "accepted" so other people can see it :-)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `nn2` from `RANN` to find nearest neighbors within radius for clustering:

```
library(RANN)

x <- c(1, 1, 1.1, 2, 1, 2.1, 2.6)
tol=0.4
nn <- nn2(x,x,k=length(x),searchtype="radius",radius=tol)
m <- unique(apply(nn$nn.idx,1,sort), MARGIN=2)
sapply(seq_len(ncol(m)), function(i) m[which(m[,i] > 0),i])
##[[1]]
##[1] 1 2 3 5
##
##[[2]]
##[1] 4 6
##
##[[3]]
##[1] 7

x <- c(1, 1.3, 1.6)
nn <- nn2(x,x,k=length(x),searchtype="radius",radius=tol)
m <- unique(apply(nn$nn.idx,1,sort), MARGIN=2)  
sapply(seq_len(ncol(m)), function(i) m[which(m[,i] > 0),i])
##[[1]]
##[1] 1 2
##
##[[2]]
##[1] 1 2 3
##
##[[3]]
##[1] 2 3
```

Notes:

1. The call to `nn2` finds all nearest neighbors for each element of `x` with respect to all elements of `x` within a radius equalling the `tol`. The result `nn$nn.idx` is a matrix whose rows contain the indices that are nearest neighbors for each element in `x`. The matrix is dense and filled with zeroes as needed.
2. Clustering is performed by sorting each row so that unique rows can be extracted. The output `m` is a matrix where each column contains the indices in a cluster. Again, this matrix is dense and filled with zeroes as needed.
3. The resulting list is extracted by subsetting each column to remove the zero entries.

This is likely more efficient for large `x` because `nn2` uses a KD-Tree, but it suffers from the same issue for elements that overlap (with respect to the tolerance) as pointed out by nicola.

Comment: I guess y is the number of groups with values within the tolerance range; I don't know this beforehand

Comment: Clustering it imo a good way to go, probably this one is better in your specific case than dbscan.

Comment: @agenis: Actually, there has got to be a clustering package in R that does this. I just don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% reliable, since it uses `unique` on `list`s, but you can try:

```
unique(apply(outer(x,x,function(a,b) abs(a-b)<tol),1,which))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 5
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4 6
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 7
```

The point @Roland raised in the comments showed that there is some ambiguity  in your requirements. For instance if `x<-c(1, 1.3, 1.6)`, my line gives three groups: 1-2, 2-3 and 1-2-3. This because, from the `1` point of view, it is similar only to `1.3`, but from `1.3` point of view, it is similar to both `1` and `1.6`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, you're right about the overlapping

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a hammer to kill a mosquito, but i thought of univariate density clustering: the `dbscan` library enables you to do exactly that:

```
library(dbscan)
groups <- dbscan(as.matrix(x), eps=tol, minPts=1)$cluster
#### [1] 1 1 1 2 1 2 3
```

You don't neek to know in advance the number of groups.

It gives you the cluster number in output but you can if you prefer, take the groups means and round them to the closest integer. Once you've got this, you generate the list for instance like this:

```
    split(seq_along(x), groups)
#### $`1`
#### [1] 1 2 3 5
#### ...
```

**Edit: Behaviour with overlapping:**
This algo attributes the same group to all elements that are within the range of tolerance of one other (works by proximity). So you might end up with fewer groups than expected if there is overlapping.

Comment: If there was no overlapping, they could just do `cutree(hclust(dist(x)), h = 0.4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt with `cut` function from base R. We first try to create the range vector named `sq` and then go through `x` elements that falls within any specific range.

```
sq <- seq(min(x)-tol,max(x)+tol*2,tol*2)
# [1] 0.6 1.4 2.2 3.0

sapply(1:(length(sq)-1), function(i) which(!is.na(cut(x, breaks =c(sq[i], sq[i+1])))))

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 5

# [[2]]
# [1] 4 6

# [[3]]
# [1] 7
```

It does not produce any duplicate. (no need to use `unique` as it is the case for @nicola's answer)

It works as follows, in `sapply`, first we search for elements within the range `[0.6, 1.4]`, then for `[1.4, 2.2]` and finally `[2.2, 3.0]`.